# Jenkins - transfer master to slave parameter in multi-configuration parameterized job

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to configure Jenkins as follows

- a master (Linux)
- a slave (Windows)
- a multi-configuration job that runs on both platforms

  - the job has a parameter VERSION, that is used to create the final archive, if compilation and testing are successful

I face the following problem. On the master, the compilation script finds the VERSION variable and everything runs fine. On the slave, the VERSION variable does not exist and the script fails. I run a python script and I get variables through the os.environ(), but the problem is that the VERSION variable does not seem to be transferred from the master environment to the slave. In fact, also a "set" command with a shell shows that the variable does not exist under Windows slave.

I found some hints that [Jenkins EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin should solve my problems. However, I did not manage to configure it properly.

May you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin/) to transport parameters between your projects. But I am not sure that works or not under your enviroment.